# How to add the user role in the registration form

Tags: wordpress, roles, user-registration

I want to display the user role field in the wordpress user registration form.

I did not see any option form the admin side.

How will I do this? So that the user select his role in the registration form. If he is a student then he will select student role otherwise staff.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress, the roles are stored in $wp_roles global variable. So, if you want to display all the roles try this:

```
global $wp_roles;

foreach ($wp_roles->roles as $role) {
    echo $role['name'];
}
```